# How do I ask the user if they want to play again and repeat the while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested

Running on Python, this is an example of my code:

```
import random 

comp = random.choice([1,2,3])

while True:
     user = input("Please enter 1, 2, or 3: ")
     if user == comp
             print("Tie game!")
     elif (user == "1") and (comp == "2")
             print("You lose!")
             break
     else:
             print("Your choice is not valid.")
```

So this part works. However, how do I exit out of this loop because after entering a correct input it keeps asking "Please input 1,2,3".

I also want to ask if the player wants to play again:

**Psuedocode:**

```
     play_again = input("If you'd like to play again, please type 'yes'")
     if play_again == "yes"
         start loop again
     else:
         exit program
```

Is this related to a nested loop somehow?

Comment: What do you mean "correct input"? Your program allows at most "Tie game!". Is this after entering a correct input? Do you want to break the loop after that? If yes, then you can easily follow the same pattern of the "You lose!" case...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Points for your code:

1. Code you have pasted don't have `':'` after `if,elif` and `else.`
2. Whatever you want can be achived using Control Flow Statements like `continue and break`. [Please check here for more detail](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).
3. You need to remove break from "YOU LOSE" since you want to ask user whether he wants to play.
4. Code you have written will never hit "Tie Game" since you are comparing string with integer. User input which is saved in variable will be string and `comp` which is output of random will be integer. You have convert user input to integer as `int(user)`.
5. Checking user input is valid or not can be simply check using `in` operator.

**Code:**

```
import random

while True:
     comp = random.choice([1,2,3])
     user = raw_input("Please enter 1, 2, or 3: ")
     if int(user) in [1,2,3]:
         if int(user) == comp:
            print("Tie game!")
         else:
            print("You lose!")
     else:
            print("Your choice is not valid.")

     play_again = raw_input("If you'd like to play again, please type 'yes'")
     if play_again == "yes":
        continue
     else:
         break
```

Comment: @Lizzie - Please check the updated code and comments